# Fridge is not cooling

Tags: refrigerator, cooling

When I was cleaning my fridge to remove the ice from the fridge, Accidentally my I made a hole in the bottom plate of the fridger and some liquid start leaking, I guess it's a coolant. After that my fridge is not cooling. Can you please help me with the resolution ?

Comment: Yes, buy a new fridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you've hit one of the refrigerant lines, and let the magic juice out. This is a very common cause of refrigerator failure. Unfortunately, if it's even possible to repair the damage, it'll likely cost more for the repair than for a new fridge.  Of course that completely depends on the make and model of the unit, and how accessible the damaged section of tubing is.

Next time you want to defrost the freezer, follow the manufacturer's defrost procedure. Stabbing at the ice with pointy bits, is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

With the freon line punctured a HVAC service call will be needed to advise if they are able to seal the line, pump it down to a vacuum and recharge. It would best to not run the fridge because air is getting in the system and the compressor life will be shortened if you do try to have it repaired. If it is a nice fridge it may be worth the cost if it is a low end model it may be cheaper to replace it.